How to activate Chrome's DOM Distiller with Javascript?
Is there any way to activate Chrome's DOM Distiller with a (console) Javascript? - like to set --enable-dom-distiller flag from console?
Background: I have a software with an in-build Chromium. I have there no access to flags - but do have it to console.

In Windows you can send a message to the app from an external utility e.g. on pressing F1 key in AutoHotkey: F1::postMessage 0x111,40273,0,,A however it'll only work if this software didn't change the id of the internal commands.

Here's how you can activate it using JavaScript:
Open the Chrome Developer Tools Console:
Press Ctrl + Shift + J (Windows/Linux) or Cmd + Option + J (Mac) to open the Developer Tools and go to the Console tab.
Paste and Execute the Following Script:
Copy the following JavaScript code and paste it into the Console, then press Enter to execute it:


javascript: (function() {
    var uri = 'https://www.google.com/reader/view/?url=' + encodeURIComponent(window.location.href);
    window.location.href = uri;
})();




The question is about a built-in function in Chrome, but this is generating a link to an external service. And the result for me is a redirect to https://www.google.com/reader/about/ which then gives a 404 page.

Once upon a time, that would have been the URL for Google Reader, a completely unrelated service, which shut down over 10 years ago.
